# VBA UBound Function

Tags: vba, excel, function

I'm trying to explore UBound applications for my code in Visual Basic for Applications (VBA). Let's say I have a 4 by 2 array...(A1:B4) and I want to count the number of rows. I would think my code would be...

```
Function test(list) As Double
   test = UBound(list)
End Function
```

My input is `=test(A1:B4)`but so far I get "#value!" error. I thought the return would be 4.

What am I doing wrong? I know how to get the number of rows using the row command but I simply want to go through the coding exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List` is range object not an array.  `Range.Value` will return an array of values from a range and `Range.Formula` will return an array of formulas from a range.

[image]

```
Function test(list As Range) As Double

    test = UBound(list.Value)

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not `Dim` `list` explicitly, it is `Variant`. So if you call `=TEST(A1:B4)` it will be a `Range` and not an `Array`. A `Range` does not have a `UBound` but does have `Rows.Count`.

So:

```
Function test(list As Range) As Double
 test = list.Rows.Count
End Function
```

will work.

Or if you really need an `Array`, you could do:

```
Function test(list As Variant) As Double
 list = list
 test = UBound(list)
End Function
```

The `list = list` does the following: If `list` is a `Range`-Object then it will be implicit converted to `Array` since `Set` is not used to set an object. If `list` is an `Array` already, then it will be also an `Array` after that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have 2-dimensional array, therefore you have to provide additional parameter for `UBound` like:

```
UBound(array, dimension)
```

Please remember, if you get array from Excel Range than it is 1-based array.

Complete solution can look like this one:

```
Function testArrray(List, Dimmension)

    Dim ListConverted As Variant
        ListConverted = List
    testArrray = UBound(ListConverted, Dimmension)
End Function
```

Sample call: `=testArrray(G15:H20,1)` produces `6` as a result which is correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you get the number of rows in a function.

```
Option Explicit

Function l_number_of_rows(rng_range As Range) As Long

    l_number_of_rows = rng_range.Rows.Count

End Function
```

if you want the one from the dimension, this is a possible solution.

```
Sub test()

    Dim MyArray(1 To 2, 0 To 3)     As Long
    MyArray(1, 0) = 10
    MyArray(1, 1) = 11
    MyArray(1, 2) = 12
    MyArray(1, 3) = 13
    MyArray(2, 0) = 20
    MyArray(2, 1) = 21
    MyArray(2, 2) = 22
    MyArray(2, 3) = 23

    Debug.Print MyArray(UBound(MyArray), 3)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The UBound function is to give you elements in a variant array, you're passing it a range.  You could try this:

```
Sub mains()
    Dim myRange As Range, myArray As Variant
    Set myRange = Range("A1:B4")
    myArray = myRange.Value
    Debug.Print test(myArray)
End Sub
Function test(list) As Double

    test = UBound(list)

End Function
```

**EDIT** With a two dimensional range (as mentioned by KazimierzJawor) the default ubound  will be the vertical, as you wanted, if you want to specify, you can add the optional perameter UBound(list, 1), but with the data you specified this defults to 4 as you wished

Answer (score 0):

Ubound is a function that works on arrays you are passing it a range

try this

```
dim i(3)
i(0) = 1
i(1) =2
i(2) = 3

msgbox ubound(i)
```

Comment: Thank you all! I appreciate it